# Скриншоты для iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, appstore

Публикую приложение в AppStore, последний раз делал это года 1.5 назад.
iTunes Connect сообщает мне, что у меня не то разрешение демо-скриншотов, хотя разрешение в пикселях в точности совпадает с требуемыми - 1242x2208 (iPhone) и 2048x2732 (iPad Pro).

У меня нет iPad Pro, да и iPhone тоже нет, поэтому я снял скриншоты со своего iPad Air 2 и растянул/сжал до требуемых размеров. Не может же она это проанализировать и на основании этого отфутболить меня?

В прошлые разы не помню чтобы у меня были такие проблемы.

С эмулятора не могу снять скриншоты, потому что нужен скриншот с видеопотоком от камеры, а еще моя программа в эмуляторе совершенно по другому выглядит, другие размеры шрифтов в частности.

P.S. Проверил всё, перечитал форумы - 72 DPI, flattened, нет альфы - ни в какую... re-scale пробовал через Photoshop, GIMP 2 и стандартную утилиту просмотра изображений Apple - одно и то же, не тот размер типа

[image: пример для iPhone 8Plus по просьбе комментаторов] пример для iPhone 8Plus по просьбе комментаторов

Comment: Я думаю просить Вас продемонстрировать данные скриншоты бесполезно.

Comment: @Roman Podymov 2  почему безполезно? я не знаю полезно ли вам, но продемонстрировать могу...

Comment: Я о том, что ежели проект не Ваш, то вряд ли можно до выхода его новой версии разбрасываться его скриншотами.

Comment: А как Вы предоставленный скриншот сделали?

Comment: @Roman Podymov проект не мой (моего заказчика вестимо), но в скриншотах нет ничего такого... я написал как его зделал - снял через свой iPad Air 2 и изменил размер с помощью GIMP2

Comment: Я имею в виду, через какую программу Вы растягивали скриншот?

Comment: @Roman Podymov пробовал re-scale с помощью GIMP2 и Photoshop - результат один и то же, не принимает Apple - разрешение требуемое в точности, 72 DPI, flattered, no alpha

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71891/discussion-between-roman-podymov-and-eugene-bartosh).

Comment: Простите, а что вам мешает сделать скриншоты в эмуляторах (особенно для iPad)? Получится размер именно тот, что требуется. Только учитывайте zoom, как ни странно, он влияет на размер скриншотов.

Comment: @Ivan Kramarchuk про эмулятор у меня в вопросе целый параграф написан, почитывайте ;-)

Comment: @EugeneBartosh извините, был невнимателен )

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился, дело в том что под сафари на Mac почему-то не было видно иконок выбора типа устройства - поэтому я закидывал скриншоты на первый девайс (iPhoneX с 5.8') - они естественно не подходили. 
Под Хромом на Mac тоже не видно, в под Хромом на винде всё отлично видно и работает - такое вот у Apple хозяйство...

[image: скриншот]